Unclear step in proof that convex functions are locally Lipschitz (Ruszczyński Lemma $2.70$)
The following is a Lemma from Ruszczyński "Nonlinear Optimization".
Question: I have reproduced the Lemma and its proof below in its entirety, however I just have a question about one step: The sentence enclosed by $\star$s below, starting with "Hence..." For the life of me, I cannot see how the author reaches the inequality in this sentence.
I have tried various algebraic manipulations of the inequalities that came before it, but I could not find something that worked to give this inequality. Where does this inequality come from?
Lemma 2.70. Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. For every $x \in \text{int} \, \text{dom}\, f$, there exists $\delta > 0$ and $L$ such that
$$|f(y) - f(x)| \leq L \|y - x\| \quad \text{whenever } \|y - x\| < \delta.$$
Proof.
Since $x \in \text{int} \, \text{dom} \, f$, we can choose a small simplex $S$ about $x$ such that it is included in the domain of $f$. Every point $y$ of the simplex is a convex combination of its vertices $v^1, \dots, v^{n+1}$ with some nonnegative coefficients $a_1, \dots, a_{n+1}$ satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i = 1$. By the convexity of $f$,
$$
f(y) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i f(v^i) \leq \max_{1 \leq i \leq n+1} f(v^i) = M.
$$
Let $\epsilon > 0$ be the lower bound on the distance from $x$ to the boundary of $S$. Suppose $\|y - x\| < \epsilon / 2$. We can represent $y$ as a convex combination of $x$ and a point $w$ at which the line passing through $x$ and $y$ intersects the boundary of $S$ (we choose the intersection point that is closer to $y$). We have
$$
y = (1 - \alpha)x + \alpha w,
$$
with
$$
\alpha = \frac{\|y - x\|}{\|w - x\|} \leq \frac{\|y - x\|}{\epsilon}.
$$
By the convexity of $f$,
$$
f(y) - f(x) \leq \alpha[f(w) - f(x)] \leq \alpha[M - f(x)] \leq \frac{M - f(x)}{\epsilon} \|y - x\|.
$$
We can also represent $x$ as a convex combination of $y$ and the point $z$ at which the same line crosses the boundary of $S$ on the other side:
$$
x = (1 - \beta)y + \beta z,
$$
with
$$
\beta = \frac{\|y - x\|}{\|y - z\|} \leq \frac{\|y - x\|}{\epsilon}.
$$
By the convexity of $f$,
$$
f(x) \leq (1 - \beta)f(y) + \beta f(z) \leq (1 - \beta)f(y) + \beta M.
$$
$\star$ Hence,
$$
f(y) - f(x) \geq \frac{2(f(x) - M)}{\epsilon} \|y - x\|. \star
$$
Combining the last inequality with (2.28), we conclude that
$$
|f(y) - f(x)| \leq \frac{2(M - f(x))}{\epsilon} \|y - x\| \quad \text{whenever } \|y - x\| < \epsilon / 2.
$$
The required inequality is satisfied with $L = \frac{2(M - f(x))}{\epsilon}$. $\Box$

Your statement enclosed by $\star$ had $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ swapped; I fixed it

That was directly from the book. Typo!

Ah, but see: https://books.google.com/books?id=41dhYmzMSm4C&q=intersects+the+boundary#v=onepage&q&f=false

I guess I typed it wrong then. Either way, I couldn't figure out how it was deduced, so thanks.

From the inequality
$$f(x) \leq (1 - \beta)f(y) + \beta f(z) \leq (1 - \beta)f(y) + \beta M\tag1$$
deduce
$$f(x)-f(y)\le\beta(M-f(y)).\tag2$$ Since $\beta\le\frac{\|y-x\|}\epsilon\le\frac12$ [this second inequality is the key condition which hasn't been used yet] and $M-f(y)$ is nonnegative, conclude
$$f(x)-f(y)\le\frac12(M-f(y)),$$ which rearranges into
$$M-f(y)\le 2(M-f(x)).\tag3$$
Substitute (3) into (2), obtaining
$$f(x)-f(y)\le\beta(M-f(y))\le\beta\cdot 2(M-f(x))\le\frac{2(M-f(x))}\epsilon\|y-x\|,$$ which gives the desired $\star$inequality$\star$.
